# Label не отображает количество строк

Tags: delphi

```
sLabel3.Caption := IntToStr(txtChkList.Lines.Count);
```

`где txtChkList - это memo. Весь прикол в том, что строки в txtChkList возникают, а sLabel3 их не отображает.

Код вроде правильный, либо я не догоняю, либо лыжи не едут.

Answer (score 2):

все работает:

```
 procedure TForm1.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
  begin
   Label1.Caption:= IntToStr(Memo1.Lines.Count);
  end;
```